# Stuck at FreeCodeCamp Trest

Tags: html, css, checkbox

First, I'd like to apologise in advance for the (probably) dumbest question ever asked here. I started the FreeCodeCamp Responsive Web Design course less than a month ag. When I finally got to the HTML test, I totally got stuck in the "All your checkboxes inside #survey-form should have a value attribute and value." I have a value attribute and a value, I tried fixing it in several different ways, asked ChatGPT, fixed all errors that showed up on validator.w3, but I still get the same error. In my desperate pursuit, I found this site.

Everything else in my code passes the test. I had a few other very silly issues, but I managed to fix, however, no matter how much I change this checkbox fieldset, I still get the same error.

Here's is my current code for checkboxes:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose the position you're applying for:</legend>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Freelance Translator" id="job1" value="Freelance Translator">
  <label for="job1">Freelance Translator</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Data Analyst" id="job2" value="Data Analyst">
  <label for="job2">Data Analyst</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Project Manager" id="job3" value="Project Manager">
  <label for="job3">Project Manager</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Project Engineer" id="job4" value="Project Engineer">
  <label for="job4">Project Engineer</label>
</fieldset>
```

I tried to change the value to a number and it didn't work. I changed the value to "option1, option2," etc, and it didn't work. I also tried changing the name attribute, but this also won't work.

Here's my entire code, in case anyone has time and patience to check it out.
https://gist.github.com/403-Lux/775b97c0a531437f921e18ebdf772ce4

I super appreciate any help I can get. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: _"should have a value attribute and value"_ - I suppose the latter part means that value should not be empty? But those both appear to be the case in your shown test HTML. Maybe the test tool is picky about the order of the attributes (which it shouldn't be, that doesn't matter in HTML) - or it is otherwise faulty.

Comment: (The _names_ you have given your checkboxes probably do make rather little sense though.)

Comment: (_"Choose the position you're applying for:"_ - if that really is supposed to be _singular_, and singular only - then those should probably be radio buttons instead of checkboxes to begin with.)

Comment: <fieldset>
  <label for="terms-conditions"><input type="checkbox" id="terms-conditions"> I accept the my data will be stored safely.</label>
</fieldset>

Comment: No value in the above